# How to select all elements with tag name 'div' but from another html?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get all elements with tag 'div' but which are located on external page.
I understand that for getting innerHTML of each DIV that is located on external page we have jquery load function which allows you to specify an element id to load.
That's useful but I would like to know how to first find all that divs? 
If I had just one html file I would use
`var divs= document.getElementsByTagName('div');`   but I don't know what to do in this case

Comment: How is your external page loaded? `iframe`, `window.open` ...? Is it on the same domain?

Comment: It's just another html file on the same domain.

Comment: So first you have to load it somehow. How are you planning to do that?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, you are saying that it's external, so I assume that it's loaded from within another page. How are you loading that external file?

Comment: Sorry, I load it using window.open

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? It's likely that you can learn from others who have tried before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have the URL of the other page, you can get the HTML of the page as a string using `XMLHttpRequest`. Save that string into a variable `html`. Then you can do:

```
var externalPage = document.createElement("div");
externalPage.innerHTML = html;
var divs = externalPage.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

Now `divs` is the `NodeList` of *div* elements of the other page.

If you already opened the other page using `window.open()`, you can instead use the return value of that call to access its `document` object:

```
var otherWindow = window.open("http://example.com/");
var divs = otherWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

Note that in both cases you are subject to the same-origin policy.

Comment: At the end I realized that only your first suggestion works for me. 
So I solved it this way http://jsfiddle.net/TCx2f/1/ 

However, thank you very much. You helped me alot!